# Redirect to 403 Forbidden component in Blazor WebAssembly

Tags: c#, authentication, blazor, http-status-code-403, webassembly

I'm currently working on a **.NET Standard 2.1 Blazor WebAssembly Hosted** application.

In my authentication scheme I use **User Roles**.

I want to redirect all users to a `<ForbiddenView />` if a user is not in a role i.e. **Admin**.

It would be nice to handle this on one place in the application.

- My App.razor looks like this:

```
   <CascadingAuthenticationState>
        <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
            <Found Context="routeData">
                <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData">
                    <Authorizing>
                        <p>Authorizing...</p>
                    </Authorizing>
                    <NotAuthorized>
                        @if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                        {
                           // User is not authenticated - forward to login view
                            <LoginView />
                        }
                        else if(context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && context.User.Identity.NotInRole) // .NotInRole does not exist!!
                        {
                            // 403 - User is authenticated, but not in a specific role i.e. admin to view a page in my app. The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
                            <ForbiddenView />
                        }
                        else
                        {
                           // 401 - Login of my user happend - the request already includes Authorization credentials.
                            <NotAuthorizedView />
                        }
                    </NotAuthorized>
                </AuthorizeRouteView>
            </Found>
            <NotFound>
                <NotFoundView />
            </NotFound>
        </Router>
    </CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

Do you know how to handle the 403 error in Blazor WebAssembly in a centralized way?

Do you have any suggests on how to handle the 403 error on Blazor WebAssembly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using AuthorizeView with a different context :

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData">
                <Authorizing>
                    <p>Authorizing...</p>
                </Authorizing>
                <NotAuthorized>
                    <AuthorizeView Context="authenticated">
                        <Authorized Context="authenticated">
                            <AuthorizeView Roles="WhatEver" Context="role">
                                <Authorized Context="role">
                                    <NotAuthorizedView />
                                </Authorized>
                                <NotAuthorized Context="role">
                                    <ForbiddenView />
                                </NotAuthorized>
                            </AuthorizeView>
                        </Authorized>
                        <NotAuthorized Context="authenticated">
                            <RedirectToLogin />
                        </NotAuthorized>
                    </AuthorizeView>
                </NotAuthorized>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <NotFoundView />
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

or `!context.User.IsInRole("WhatEver");`

if you specifically need NotInRole:

```
public static bool NotInRole(this ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal) 
    => claimsPrincipal.Claims.All(c => c.Type != "role");
```

Answer (score 0):

For all lost link - .html vs .jpg ...:

```
app.UseStatusCodePages("text/html" , "<html><head><meta charset=\"utf-8\"/></head><body><br/><br/><br><br><br><center><h1>فعلا اینجا چیزی نیست - تا بعد<br/><hr/>{0}</h1><center></body></html>");
```

vs

```
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/err/?id={0}");
//(Read Error and get page for this error: 403 - 404 ...)
//"Error" folder not allowed!! - use "err" folder
```

vs direct-redirect without id

```
 app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/err/{0}");
```

> ```
> 400 (Bad request)
> 401 (Authorization required)
> 402 (Payment required)
> 403 (Forbidden)
> 404 (Not found)
> 405 (Method not allowed)
> 406 (Not acceptable)
> 407 (Proxy authentication required)
> 408 (Request timeout)
> 409 (Conflict)
> 410 (Gone)
> 411 (Length required)
> 412 (Precondition failed)
> 413 (Request entity too large)
> 414 (Request URI too large)
> 415 (Unsupported media type)
> 416 (Request range not satisfiable)
> 417 (Expectation failed)
> 422 (Unprocessable entity)
> 423 (Locked)
> 424 (Failed dependency)
> 500 (Internal server error)
> 501 (Not Implemented)
> 502 (Bad gateway)
> 503 (Service unavailable)
> 504 (Gateway timeout)
> 505 (HTTP version not supported)
> 506 (Variant also negotiates)
> 507 (Insufficient storage)
> 510 (Not extended)
> ```